# A new kind of calculus

Tags: calculus, general-topology

I was looking at a few results from topology and I came across the fact that we can define a topology on $\mathbb{R}$ such that every function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous. Now I was wondering if we can define a new kind of calculus on this topology?

My motivation in asking this question is that I believe for calculus to exist we need a notion of openness, distance and continuity. Such a topology has all three.

If such a calculus were to exist would every function be infinitely differentiable and smooth?

Comment: While it *has* a notion of distance, the notion in question is the discrete metric. This one doesn't make for a very interesting calculus.

Comment: In what sense is the calculus not interesting?

Comment: If every function is continuous then the topology has to be discrete, i.e., every set is open. I would say it does not carry any topological information.